# No permission to access on server after install opencart custom theme

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, bitnami, opencart2.3

After I install a custom theme on my bitnami opencart, some folder show

> You don't have permission to access
>   /system/config/revslider/rs-plugin/css/settings.css on this server.

I tried `chmod 755,777, 775, 644` on files and and folders but nothing works.

Comment: This has nothing to do with AWS access, but configuration of you apps.

Comment: so you down vote my answer. You have to ask me to delete that answer or you could say this is not the right procedure.

Comment: Sometime vote down is just a reminder to improve/fix your question/topics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you have CSS files at `/opt/bitnami/apps/opencart/htdocs/system/config/`? That folder should only contain the php configuration files.

All the CSS files should be under `/opt/bitnami/apps/opencart/htdocs/admin/view/javascript/` or 
`/opt/bitnami/apps/opencart/htdocs/catalog/view/javascript/`.

As you mentioned the htaccess configuration protects the **/opt/bitnami/apps/opencart/htdocs/system/** directory but Bitnami does it because of security reasons and you should not change that.

Comment: Juan I used a custom theme. So it has some css and js files in system folder.

Comment: mkdir(); permission denied in opt/bitnami/apps/opencart/htdocs/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-system_storage_modification_admin_controller_extension_installer.php What is the cause Juan?